# Typescript can resolve json file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Can I import json file without the extension in `typescript`?

for example, I have `file.json`, and this is my typescript file:
`import jsonData from './file'`.

But I got an error: [ts] Cannot find module './file'.

Comment: what's your module in typescript compilerOptions?

Comment: `module: esnext`

Answer (score 0):

try `"./file.json"` instead of `"./file"`

---

or

read json file using fs.readFile("./file.json"),
then parse it with JSON.parse()

Comment: hahaha.. the question was how to resolve without add extension.

Comment: then.. um, use fs module for reading json file like ordinary text file,

Comment: and use JSON.parse for parsing

Comment: Pleas edit your answer and not provide additional info in comments as comments are likely to be deleted.

Comment: Why, I'm curious, do you want to don't need have the extension explicitly written?